# How to display image in jsp from server using webservices or servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to display images from server on jsp page. Images are stored in folder of server. I am using servlet and my code is:

```
       File folderFile = new File(homeDir);
       File[] uplodedFiles = folderFile.listFiles();
       for (int i = 0; i < uplodedFiles.length; i++) {
            byte[] imageBytes = getImageAsBytes(uplodedFiles[0].getAbsolutePath());
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
            response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
```

How to display image on jsp page? Please give me suggestion with code.

Comment: You can't send multiple images in one response. One request to one image --> one response with one image.

Comment: @ JB Nizet thanks.. Then how to possible this? Please give me another suggestion.

Comment: Your JSP must generate one `<img src="theServlet?imageId=..."/>` per image you want to display. The browsr will then send one request for each image, and the servlet just has to read and send the appropriate image, based on the imageId parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your images are stored on a folder that can be served by your server, you just need to add  elements to your JSP pages and have their 'src' attribute hold the path to your image.

For instance, let's say you're storing your images in a folder named 'images' that can be served by your server. You'll have to insert a  element in your JSP page such as:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/images/image_name.jpg" /img>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
try{
         String fileName = request.getParameter("image");             
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("d:\\"+fileName));
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);             
         response.setContentType(contentType);
         BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
         for (int data; (data = bis.read()) > -1;) {
           output.write(data);
         }             
      }
      catch(IOException e){

      }finally{
          // close the streams
      }
```

For passing the image path you can use src like this

```
<img src="<%=request.getParameter("image")%>">
```

Comment: @ Vignesh Vino thanks. String fileName = request.getParameter("image"); Is right? I think its will be request.serParameter("image");

Comment: Make it accordingly..Its just an example